# AHK wait for more presses of hotkey to cycle through options

Tags: autohotkey

I'm doing some work with AHK to control Excel using COM. The idea of the current script is to have the script do a different option for freezing an excel sheet each time the hotkey is clicked. In this case, it is ^f:: (CTRL+f)

My thinking, was to have a 5 second timer, and to wait for concurrent presses, running the freezing function each time. After 5 seconds, the script terminates.

I feel like this is a rather simple implementation with WaitKey, but I haven't had any luck. I can't quite wrap my head around how to use the ErrorLevel and implement it with my function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been looking at the documentation and other posts and I haven't been able to get it figured. I wrote some pseudo-code below to sorta give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
press_cycle :=0

;; while KeyWait timer hasn't run out:
;;     wait for additional presses of hotkey
;;     if press 
;;         reset 5 sec timer
;;         run cycle_freezing() again 

cycle_freezing(){
    if (press_cycle = 3){
        MsgBox, "unfreezing"
        xl.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes := False
        press_cycle := 0
    }
    if (press_cycle = 2){ ;; freeze header and selected column
        MsgBox, "freezing header and selected"
        ;XL_Freeze(xl,Row:=header_row,Col:=column)
        press_cycle := 3
    }
    if (press_cycle = 1){ ;; freeze header and first column
        MsgBox, "freezing header and first col"
        ;XL_Freeze(xl,Row:=header_row,Col:="B")
        press_cycle := 2
    }
    if (press_cycle = 0){ ;; freeze header
        MsgBox, "freezing header"
        XL_Freeze(xl,Row:=header_row,Col:="A")
        press_cycle := 1
    }
}
;***********************Freeze Panes********************************.
;~ XL_Freeze(XL,Row:="1",Col:="B") ;Col A will not include cols which is default so leave out if unwanted
;***********************Freeze Panes in Excel********************************.
XL_Freeze(xl,Row="",Col=""){
    xl.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes := False ;unfreeze in case already frozen
    IfEqual,row,,return ;if no row value passed row;  turn off freeze panes
    xl.Application.ActiveSheet.Range(Col . Row+1).Select ;; Helps it work more intuitivly 
                                                         ;; 1 includes 1 not start at zero
    xl.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes := True
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're asking for, but I'm not sure by terminating the script you actually mean terminating the script? Doesn't sound sensible to me.

```
press_count := 0
^f::
    if(!press_count) ;zero evaluates to false
        ToolTip, % "Action that should happen after the 1st press"
    else if (press_count = 1)
        ToolTip, % "Action that should happen after the 2nd press"
    else if (press_count = 2)
        ToolTip, % "Action that should happen after the 3rd press"
    else
        ToolTip, % "Action that should happen after the 4th press"

    if(!press_count) ;if we're on the very first keypress
        SetTimer, ExitTimerCallback, -5000 ;set the timer, -5000 means it'll run ONCE after 5000ms
    else
        SetTimer, ExitTimerCallback ;otherwise reset the timer's period
    press_count++ ;increase by one
return

ExitTimerCallback:
    ExitApp
return
```

And here's a version that makes more sense to me, this is probably what you meant to ask for?

```
^f::
    if(A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 5000)
        press_count++ ;increase by one if we're inside that 5sec window
    else
        press_count := 1 ;reset otherwise
    if(press_count = 1)
        ToolTip, % "Action that should happen after the 1st press"
    else if (press_count = 2)
        ToolTip, % "Action that should happen after the 2nd press"
    else if (press_count = 3)
        ToolTip, % "Action that should happen after the 3rd press"
    else
        ToolTip, % "Action that should happen after the 4th press"
return
```

I wanted to give the [`A_TimeSincePriorHotkey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#h) variable some recognition.
Be sure to keep in mind that the variable is not just for that `^f` hotkey though, if your script is bigger and you're triggering other hotkeys as well, consider switching to the timer approach as I showed above. Just instead of exiting, reset the `press_count` variable.

You also didn't say what should happen if it's pressed more than four times, I'll leave that up to you.